# Know about how to stop the Sound within the loop after user input

Tags: python

I wanted to ask that how I can play the sound in loop and then when the user click ENTER the music stops and the loop break like in this #help here that's the place where I wanted it to loop till the user gives the input to stop and also how can we add a counter that will run in the background of the program while other things are being done like print and taking input like this.

```
import time
import sys
from time import strftime,localtime
from pygame import mixer
import os
import pyautogui as spam

mixer.init() #Initialzing pyamge mixer
tick=mixer.Sound('sounds/245764888.mp3')

def delete_last_line():
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

def clock():
    time=strftime("At: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p", localtime())
    print(time)

def tk():
    for i in range(2):
            print(".")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            delete_last_line();            print("..");            time.sleep(0.3);            delete_last_line();            print("...");            time.sleep(0.3);          delete_last_line();            print("....");            time.sleep(0.3);            delete_last_line()

ringtone=mixer.Sound('sounds/pill.wav') #Loading Music File as Sound

while True:
    samay=0
    os.system("cls")

    print("Started",end=" ");clock()
    time_inout_frm_usr=int(input('\nEnter the times in seconds: '))



    while samay<time_inout_frm_usr:
        samay+=1
        tick.play()
        print(samay)
        time.sleep(1)
        delete_last_line()
        
        if samay==time_inout_frm_usr:
            ringtone.play(-1)
            print('\nTIME OUT!!!\n')
            print("Ended",end=" ");clock()
            ask_to_stop=input("Press Enter to stop")
            delete_last_line()                               #help here
            if ask_to_stop=='':
                ringtone.stop()
            break

    ask_cont=input("\nTo use again [ENTER] to continue or [NO] to close: ")
    if ask_cont=='':
        delete_last_line()
        print("Starting again in a sec")
        tk()
    else:
        os.system("cls")
        print("Closing in a sec")
        tk()
        spam.typewrite("exit")
        spam.press("Enter")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in python, but i have a few suggestions:

in order to stop the loop, instead of using `while True`, use an actual condition, such as a variable being 1. and make it so that when enter is clicked, you add 1 to the variable. this way you can easily stop the loop.

for stopping the music, i honestly don't know the module you're using, but you can search for a code block in your module that allows you to stop the music.

these are probably the first things that come to mind, and so i doubt what i said was very helpful. That was all i could say, though. and i hope someone helps you find a more efficient solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).